# Do table statistics get updated during the creation of a clustered index?

Tags: sql-server, clustered-index, table-statistics

After I have created a clustered index on a table, is there any point in updating the statistics for that table?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the statistics will of been updated automatically on the index creation.

If anything an update statistics will make it worse since it will default to samping the data, where as the index creation looked at all the data. sp_update_stats checks the row modification counter to prevent uncessary updates, so would not show a difference, but I'm not sure if directly issuing a update statistics command on the table would check first.

Answer (score 2):

No, create or rebuild will update stats, however reorganize (defrag of indexes) will not update the stats